# ¿Cómo puedo editar el contenido de un contenedor con jquery o javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3, responsive

me gustaría que los datos que tiene mi contenido cambie por el contenido que se agregue  al rellenar los inputs, pero que solo cambien los textos y las imágenes, que no cambie el color ni nada de lo demás.

Soy nuevo en esto así que me sería de mucha ayuda la información que me puedan proporcionar, no sé como crear esos múltiples div al dar click en el botón, lo que necesito precisamente es que al dar click en el botón crear, se agregue lo mismo, solo que los textos de los nombres y la fecha cambien de acuerdo a lo que se introduzca en los inputs.

[image: Imagen del contenedor con el contenido]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var container = $('#containert'),
        team1 = $('#team1'),
        team2 = $('#team2'),
        date = $('#date');

    $('#crear').on('click', function(){
        var caja = $('<div></div>').attr('class', 'containert').add({
        $(contenedor).addClass('container');
        $(contenedor).addClass('next-match');
        $(contenedor).addClass('header-board');
        $(contenedor).addClass('result');
        });
        contenedor.after(caja);


    });

});
```

```css
div.container{
    display: flex;
}
section#next-match{
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 3em auto 0 auto;
    width: 24rem;
    border-radius: 0.1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0em 0.0625em 0.6875em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47); /* 0/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 11/16 */ /* 2/16 */
    -moz-box-shadow:    0em 0.0625em 0.6875em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47); /* 0/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 11/16 */ /* 2/16 */
    box-shadow:         0em 0.0625em 0.6875em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47); /* 0/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 11/16 */ /* 2/16 */
}

section#next-match .result{
    font-family: 'go3';
    margin: inherit;
}

section#next-match div.header-board{
    border-radius: 0em 0em 1em 1em;
    background-color: #141414;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 1em;
    text-shadow: 0em 0.125em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* 0/16 */ /* 2/16 */ /* 2/16 */
    letter-spacing: 0.125em; /* 2/16 */
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0em 0.0625em 0.625em 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27); 
    -moz-box-shadow:    0em 0.0625em 0.625em 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
    box-shadow:         0em 0.0625em 0.625em 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27); /* 0/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 10/16 */ /* 0/16 */
}
section#next-match div.header-board .on{
  font-family: 'glacial-bold';
  color: red;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -.9em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transition: 200ms

  

}
section#next-match div.header-board .on span{
  color: red;
  font-size: 3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:inherit;
}
section#next-match div.header-board .on:hover{
  color: white;
}
section#next-match div.content{
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
section#next-match div.clan-pics{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2em 0 2em 0;
}
section#next-match ul{
    display: inline-flex;
    text-align: center;
}
section#next-match div.clan-pics li{
    margin: 0 2em 0 2em;
}
section#next-match div.clan-pics li:first-child{
    margin-right: 3em;
    border-radius: 0.9375em;
}
section#next-match div.clan-pics li:last-child{
    margin-left: 3em;
}
section#next-match img{
    width: 5.625em; /* 90/16 */
    border: 0.125em solid #fff; /* 2/16 */
    border-radius: 5em;
}
section#next-match div.versus{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #141414;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    border-radius: 0.9375em; /*0.9375em 1em*/ /* 15/16 */
}
section#next-match div.versus li{
    color: #a6a6a6;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-family: 'glacial', sans-serif;

}
section#next-match div.versus ul li .first{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0em 0.125em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* 0/16 */ /* 2/16 */ /* 2/16 */
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-right: 3.125em; /* 50/16 */
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'glacial', sans-serif;
    cursor: none;
}

section#next-match div.versus ul li .second{
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0em 0.125em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* 0/16 */ /* 2/16 */ /* 2/16 */
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: 2.8em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'glacial', sans-serif;
}


section#next-match div.date{
    padding: 2em 0 1em 0;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
    font-family: 'go3', sans-serif;
}

/*INPUTS*/


input[type="text"] {
    background: rgba(189, 188, 188, 0.4);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
    font-family: "glacial";
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 0.0625em solid rgba(242, 227, 227, 1.0); /* 1/16 */
}

.send {
    border: none;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    background: rgba(78, 4, 4, .4);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
    font-family: "glacial";
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.0625em solid rgba(242, 227, 227, 1.0); /* 1/16 */
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
    <section id="next-match" class="next-match">
      <div class="header-board">
        <h2 class="result">Resultados</h2>
          <div class="on"><span>•</span>En Vivo</div>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <div class="clan-pics">
              <ul>
                <li class="left-pics"><img src="images/gl-banner2.png" alt="GOD LEVEL OFFICIAL"></li>
                <li class="right-pics"><img src="images/gl-banner.png" alt="GOD LEVEL Logo"></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="versus" id="versus">
              <ul>
                <li><h2 class="first" id="first">GOD LEVEL</h2></li>
                <li>VS</li>
                <li><h2 class="second" id="second">BITE SNAKE</h2></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="date" id="date"><span>JULY 20, 2018, 9:30PM</span></div>
          </div>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </section>

 
  </div> <!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema se puede resolver sencillamente utilizando los métodos **[.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector)**, **[.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)** y **[.appendTo()](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/#appendTo-target)** de jQuery.

Tuve que hacerle varias modificaciones a tu código. Por ejemplo:

Suponiendo que es la etiqueta **section** la que se va a clonar para posteriormente ser insertada en tu div **container**, lo recomendable es remover/quitar todos los IDs porque siempre deberás evitar que haya IDs **duplicados** en tu DOM (de la misma página), por lo tanto nos concentraremos en sus **clases**.

Por lo mismo tuve que cambiar las reglas de tu CSS para que apunten a una **clase** y no a un ID.

Se me olvidó mencionar que a partir de la 2da clonación se debe tener cuidado porque como estamos ubicando el elemento **section** por **clase**, entonces al clonar por segunda ocasión estaría encontrando 2 elementos section, por lo que ahora estaría clonando 2 secciones en lugar de solo una, y así sucesivamente. Para evitar esto, se debe utilizar la pseudo-clase **:first**, para que siempre te traiga únicamente la primer coincidencia (la sección original).

Como los elementos que vas a reemplazar en cada clon se encuentran dentro de etiquetas como **h2** y **span**, utilizaremos el método **.text()** en lugar de .val() (este se utiliza con elementos input), para establecerles su valor.

Y el ejemplo final quedaría así:

```js
//var imgIzq = "https://fuswork.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/tb.gif";
//var imgDer = "http://loodibee.com/wp-content/uploads/nfl-new-england-patriots-team-logo-2-300x300.png";
var imgIzq;
var imgDer

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('#crear').click(function(){
    
        var team1 = $("#txtTeam1");
        var team2 = $("#txtTeam2");
        var tDate = $("#txtDate");
        
        var sectionTmp = $(".next-match:first").clone();
        sectionTmp.find(".first").text(team1.val());
        sectionTmp.find(".second").text(team2.val());
        sectionTmp.find(".date").text(tDate.val());
        sectionTmp.find(".left-pics").attr("src", imgIzq);
        sectionTmp.find(".right-pics").attr("src", imgDer);
        
        //Se adjunta el clon con los nuevos datos al contenedor
        sectionTmp.appendTo("#container");
        
        //Se limpian los controles y las variables de imagen
        team1.val('');
        team2.val('');
        tDate.val('');
        $("#fotoIzq").val("");
        $("#fotoDer").val("");
        imgIzq = "";
        imgDer = "";
    });
});

function previewFile(input, posicion){
    
    var file = $(input).get(0).files[0];

    if(file){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(){
            
            if(posicion == "izq")
               imgIzq = reader.result;
            else if(posicion == "der")
               imgDer = reader.result;
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

```css
div.container{
    display: flex;
}
section.next-match{
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 3em auto 0 auto;
    width: 24rem;
    border-radius: 0.1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0em 0.0625em 0.6875em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47); /* 0/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 11/16 */ /* 2/16 */
    -moz-box-shadow:    0em 0.0625em 0.6875em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47); /* 0/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 11/16 */ /* 2/16 */
    box-shadow:         0em 0.0625em 0.6875em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47); /* 0/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 11/16 */ /* 2/16 */
}

section.next-match .result{
    font-family: 'go3';
    margin: inherit;
}

section.next-match div.header-board{
    border-radius: 0em 0em 1em 1em;
    background-color: #141414;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 1em;
    text-shadow: 0em 0.125em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* 0/16 */ /* 2/16 */ /* 2/16 */
    letter-spacing: 0.125em; /* 2/16 */
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0em 0.0625em 0.625em 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27); 
    -moz-box-shadow:    0em 0.0625em 0.625em 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
    box-shadow:         0em 0.0625em 0.625em 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27); /* 0/16 */ /* 1/16 */ /* 10/16 */ /* 0/16 */
}
section.next-match div.header-board .on{
  font-family: 'glacial-bold';
  color: red;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -.9em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transition: 200ms

  

}
section.next-match div.header-board .on span{
  color: red;
  font-size: 3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:inherit;
}
section.next-match div.header-board .on:hover{
  color: white;
}
section.next-match div.content{
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
section.next-match div.clan-pics{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2em 0 2em 0;
}
section.next-match ul{
    display: inline-flex;
    text-align: center;
}
section.next-match div.clan-pics li{
    margin: 0 2em 0 2em;
}
section.next-match div.clan-pics li:first-child{
    margin-right: 3em;
    border-radius: 0.9375em;
}
section.next-match div.clan-pics li:last-child{
    margin-left: 3em;
}
section.next-match img{
    width: 5.625em; /* 90/16 */
    border: 0.125em solid #fff; /* 2/16 */
    border-radius: 5em;
}
section.next-match div.versus{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #141414;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    border-radius: 0.9375em; /*0.9375em 1em*/ /* 15/16 */
}
section.next-match div.versus li{
    color: #a6a6a6;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-family: 'glacial', sans-serif;

}
section.next-match div.versus ul li .first{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0em 0.125em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* 0/16 */ /* 2/16 */ /* 2/16 */
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-right: 3.125em; /* 50/16 */
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'glacial', sans-serif;
    cursor: none;
}

section.next-match div.versus ul li .second{
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0em 0.125em 0.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* 0/16 */ /* 2/16 */ /* 2/16 */
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: 2.8em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'glacial', sans-serif;
}


section.next-match div.date{
    padding: 2em 0 1em 0;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
    font-family: 'go3', sans-serif;
}

/*INPUTS*/


input[type="text"] {
    background: rgba(189, 188, 188, 0.4);
    /*color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);*/
    font-family: "glacial";
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 0.0625em solid rgba(242, 227, 227, 1.0); /* 1/16 */
}

.send {
    border: none;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    background: rgba(78, 4, 4, .4);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
    font-family: "glacial";
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.0625em solid rgba(242, 227, 227, 1.0); /* 1/16 */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="container">
   <section class="next-match">
      <div class="header-board">
         <h2 class="result">Resultados</h2>
         <div class="on"><span>•</span>En Vivo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
         <div class="clan-pics">
            <ul>
               <li><img class="left-pics" src="https://imgur.com/S1pJSbn.jpg" alt="GOD LEVEL OFFICIAL" width="45px" height="85px" /></li>
               <li><img class="right-pics" src="https://imgur.com/yVFIT4Z.jpg" alt="GOD LEVEL Logo"  width="45px" height="85px" /></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="versus">
            <ul>
               <li><h2 class="first">GOD LEVEL</h2></li>
               <li>VS</li>
               <li><h2 class="second">BITE SNAKE</h2></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div><span class="date">JULY 20, 2018, 9:30PM</span></div>
      </div>
   </section>
</div> <!-- END CONTAINER -->
<p>
   <input type="text" id="txtTeam1" placeholder="TEAM 1" />
   <input type="text" id="txtTeam2" placeholder="TEAM 2" />
   <input type="text" id="txtDate" placeholder="DATE" />
   <button id="crear">CREAR</button>
</p>
<p>
   <label>Seleccione imagen primer equipo</label>
   <input type="file" id="fotoIzq" name="fotoIzq" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"  onchange="previewFile(this, 'izq')" />
</p>
<p>
   <label>Seleccione imagen segundo equipo</label><input type="file" id="fotoDer" name="fotoDer" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"  onchange="previewFile(this, 'der')" />
</p>
<br><br>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias!, El código funciona, te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Podrías Ayudarme Para Que La Imagen Cambie, Por La Que Yo Suba, La De Los Logos.

Comment: @DavidGT07V: He modificado mi ejemplo para que puedas observar como harías el cambio de imágenes a partir de la primera clonación, y una aclaración respecto a porqué estoy utilizando la pseudo-clase **:this**

Comment: Muchas Gracias Lo Revisaré, ¿Hay Alguna Manera De Que Te Pueda Contactar Personalmente?

Comment: ¿Cómo Puedo Hacer Para Poner Un Input De Tipo File?

Comment: Respecto a la primer pregunta, no estoy seguro si las reglas de SO lo permitan. Y respondiendo a tu segunda pregunta, revisa **[este ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_value)**

Comment: lo revisé, Pero Luego Me Sale Solo La Ruta, No El Archivo.

Comment: Tienes razón. Una disculpa, pensé que era más sencillo. Aquí te dejo otro **[ejemplo](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)** que espero te sirva.

Comment: Disculpa Nuevamente La Molestia, ¿Podrías Ayudarme? , No Sé Si Manejas Python, Si Es Así, ¿Podrías Ayudarme A Pasar El Código A Ese Lenguaje, O Solo Que Se Repita?

Comment: Lamentablemente no tengo conocimiento de ni experiencia con Python. Yo manejo .Net

Comment: Muchas Gracias De Todas Formas.

Comment: Disculpa Nuevamente La Molestia, Estuve Probando El Código Con El Método Replace Pero No Logré Hacer Que Se Cambiaran Las Imágenes, Realmente Te Pido Disculpas, Soy Novato En Esto, Y Me Vendría Bien Tu Ayuda Y La De Los Miembros De Esta Comunidad.

Comment: ¿Puedes Ayudarme?

Comment: Disculpa la demora! Había estado muy ocupado. He modificado mi ejemplo para incluir la opción de que el usuario pueda seleccionar sus propias imágenes. Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas Gracias Y Disculpa Las Molestias.